# Appending an element to the child fires the drop event in the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm a bit confused with jquery's drag and drop behaviour.
Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu0pontg/22/):

I'm trying to check if the draggable element is dropped in the list (child) or the div (parent). It works fine if I comment the append call.
I tried inserting the [greedy option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy) in the child and checking the [event.target](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#event-target) in the parent's event handler but it always comes up as `event.target=the parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are binding `droppable` widget twice? Remove following `widget`

```
$("div.ui-droppable").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        printEventReceiver("parent",event)
    }
})
```

and, change

```
$("ul.ui-droppable").droppable({
```

to

```
$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
```

Basically, `greedy` flag work only within the context of one `widget` initialisation. So, it's better to initialise `widget` once by using some common class and remove duplicate initialisations when possible.

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/scorpy2007/yu0pontg/23/

Comment: Because they do diferent things, the child droppable handler i supposed to append the item to the list. The parent's handler will do other stuff, I just didn't put it there because it's supposed to be a minimal working example.

Comment: Please see the fiddle link provided.

Comment: Ok I can see it works and I can do a check for event.target in the common handler. Can you elaborate on what I did wrong? because I thought I was binding two different event handlers, one for div.ui-droppable and another for ul.ui-droppable.

Comment: What you did was technically correct. To stop bubbling of events, JQuery provides `greedy` flag. But that greedy flag works only within context of one `widget` creation.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. Plase edit your answer to include that explanation so that other people can understand it better. I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have added the explanation.